# Preforming geometry on a plane

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, 2d, geometry-surface

In my current c++ program I am dealing with a plane that is intersected by several other planes. I want to find the polygon formed by the lines that define the intersections of the planes. For simplicity and computation speed, it seems like my best bet is to get the lines that form the intersections and then work out the polygon in 2d on the surface of the plane. Does anyone have an idea how to translate the lines(represented by a position and a direction vector) onto the plane and the final polygon back into 3d?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this isn't possible to do. The simplest counterexample is the intersection of two planes where the two centers overlap. Viewing it edge-on, it would look like a plus sign. There is no polygon that results from this intersection; a line segment, yes, but no polygon. If you want to draw the resulting polygon, then it needs to be *convex*, as well which puts more constraints on the allowable intersection configurations.

Comment: Since I am constructing Brillouin Zones, I know that polygons will be possible